# Opening a new terminal with arguments from an existing terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, exec

In linux, I can open a new terminal by executing `gnome-terminal` command on the existing terminal, but how can i open the new terminal with arguments? I tried `gnome-terminal --command ls` but the new terminal opens and closes quickly before I can see if anything is happening there.. Any suggestions how can I do this?

Comment: have you tried using xterm?

Comment: ooh, actually it works with xterm, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xterm`

```
xterm -e command

xterm -e ls
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual teminal:

$openvt    ( No need to install anything like xterm, it is available by default in most of linux flavour )

```
e.g. $openvt ls    (Run the 'ls' on the next free VT)
```

To switch to a VT, Alt+F<1-12>